# Can I connect an Android smartphone to an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, camera, android, smartphones

I'd like to connect my main Android smartphone (it's a ZTE Blade X) to my Arduino Uno. My main reason is I'd like to use the camera on my phone as a sensor for the Arduino, for various projects.

Is this possible to do, by simply connecting the 4 wires of the phone charger into the Arduino? (The 4 wires are positive, ground, data + and data -, as I'm sure you all already know.)

Comment: There are ways, but cameras, especially phone camera, are not really useful to an Arduino.  You'd probably have to have the phone interpret the image and communicate simple conclusions to the Arduino.  Also tying your phone up in a project is inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly like you think. The 4 wires are for a USB interface, which the atmega328P on the Arduino Uno does not support. There are Arduino boards that have a USB interface AFAIK, but this won't be a trivial thing to do. Or you could add a USB to SPI breakout board, but that probably won't support high speed USB.

Another option is to use a BLE enable Arduino module/board, and connect remotely. But again, you will have a decent bit of programming to do on the phone and the Arduino.

Comment: The Uno has a USB device interface, and most Android phones can operate as hosts to use it.  But none of these ideas are likely to achieve the askers goal.

Comment: I know of ways to use my phone as a webcam for my computer. Is it possible for the arduino to look at the feed from the webcam software and interpret it from there? Im sorry, this explanation isnt very good, if theres anything youd like me to clarify please ask

Comment: @ChrisStratton Not a native interface. It has a USB -> Serial, which isn't near fast enough, nor supports any of the native USB protocols

Comment: No, image interpretation is far betyond an Arduino's capability

Comment: @kyle there is no "native USB protocols".  Android can talk to the Uno's USB chip via in-app CDC/ACM implementation, and that can talk to the main processor as fast as the main processor can realistically handle; the issue isn't where you think it is.  An Uno couldn't deal with a video feed from any source.

Comment: Well in that case, is this something i could achieve using python? My end goal was ultimately just have the serial monitor say something when, for example, the color red appeared. But i just realized that i dont need an arduino to do such a thing

Comment: You could write an andriod app to do that or if the field of view is simple get an Arduino color sensor - which is a one-pixel camera.

Comment: Well to be honest I hate programming android, whereas I really enjoy using python. But thankyou for the suggestion. And I will eventually buy many sensors but for now im trying to stick with the materials I have currently

Comment: @ChrisStratton Not to keep going back and forth with you, since we both know that this implementation won't work. But the USB to serial is limited to like what, 115k baud. USB Hi speed is like 480mb, so the serial converter absolutely limits the speed as the atmega can handle several mb speed especially if clocked at 16mhz

Comment: @KyleHunter - First, realize that because the USB serial chip on an Uno is an ATmega it has the same *full speed* USB interface that a native-USB Arduino would.  Then consider that because both chips are ATmegas with the same UART architecture they can operate at maximum baud rates without timing error.   You should be able to do 1 megabaud (theoretically 2).  Now, what sort of data flow rate do you think you can deal with in an MCU that only has 2048 bytes of RAM, even if it had a native USB interface???

Comment: @ChrisStratton The on board ftdi usb to uart chip supports a max of 3mbit. Not nearly supporting full speed: https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm

Comment: @KyleHunter No.  **An Uno does not utilize an FTDI.**  And it's still a pointless argument when the MCU can't possibly deal with a firehose worth of data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ahh. When you look on Google, I guess a lot of knockoffs use a ftdi usb to uart convertor. The official arduino uses a dedicated USB chip. Yeah either way, the atmega328 definitely can't handle the datarate

Comment: So since Arduino is out of the picture, is that a possible yes to using python to accomplish my goal? I read all of your comments but it mostly went over my head. Im only 15 and I know about 5 programming languages fairly well but python is by far the easiest in my opinion. Would it work though?

Comment: @scooter505 Perhaps you could try a raspberry pi? That has the processing power, and you can use python. I still would advise you use some other method to achieve this, like an on board pi camera or something

Comment: If you want to use python, first achieve your goal running on your PC, only then worry about moving it to something embedded.